# Comma in "нe то чтобы"

Tags: пунктуация

Do I need a comma here between "то" and "чтобы"?

> ... потому как они мясо птиц вообще никогда не едят – нe **то чтобы**
>   по каким-то дням.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you don't need a comma there.

From [gramota.ru](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_492):

> НЕ ТО ЧТОБ / ЧТОБЫ, частица
>
> Между частями выражения «не то чтобы» знаки препинания не ставятся.
>
> *Надо вам заметить, жена моя содержит музыкальную школу и частный пансион, то есть не то чтобы пансион, а так, нечто вроде.* А. Чехов, О вреде табака.